# Android and mongo

Tags: android, mongodb, mlab

I have my app connecting to a mongodb server. However it can take a long while, anywhere from 2 to 10 seconds, to run a query when i do it from my app. My collections arent big. The largest only has 527 records.

I know ideally you arent supposed to connect your app directly to the mongo db but thats how its working (for now anyway).

I was just curious about anyone else that has done this if they have had a similar problem? Im using the site mlab.com for my mongo database.

UPDATE 1:

Here is one of my queries. It gets all the players for a specified team. 10 seconds is the rare occurance but 5 is usual, getting up to 7 isnt rare at all. I call the query in an AsyncTask. I have indexes on team and name of the player collection. But with their only being 527 records anyway, its not really needed that much.

```
    uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:password@<server>/fantasydraft");
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    mongoDB = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
    MongoCollection<Document> playerCollection =  mongoDB.getCollection("players");
    String result = "";

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = playerCollection.find(
            new Document("team", team)).sort(new Document("name", 1)).iterator(); // Sort by name

    while(cursor.hasNext())
        searchResults.add(cursor.next().getString("name"));
```

The database is hosted on a site called www.mlab.com. Im gonna contact them next, but I was just curious about whether this was a problem with android directly connecting with mongo that is a known issue of some kind.

I tested a count call and it took a few seconds as well. Ive never done mongo through android before but I assume for such simple things it should be a lot quicker?

Comment: Can you show your queries and indexes ? Also simple queries like count does take 10 secs ? Where is your db is hosted and where do you try to connect it.

Comment: please see the update Cheers.

Comment: Gues what *"The database is hosted on a site called www.mlab.com."*. So should it not be self explanatory that you are working with a database directly over a remote connection link and your issue here is response time. Generally when you didn't really getit  enough to at least start your remote application in that way it scares us. It scares us because if that was not understood then chances are code like the block you show above is happening on every request. Connect database, issue query, loop cursor iteration. Yes? All of those things are bad for a remote application.

Comment: So tackling those: 1. Connect to database **once** and once only in your application and persist it. Again, this really should be happening on server API instead. 2. Issue query is generally fine, but again it still really should be happening on the Server API side. Request params you would send there are certainly lighter than the BSON command and query load going to the database. 3. Cursor iteration is bad here. Cursor iteration is generally *good*, but not over a low speed remote connection. Again the server API should package a result and send it all at once.

Comment: Thanks. As of right now I dont know any server side stuff really. Starting to learn ruby so hopefully that will help. I was just wondering about if it was me or something else. Clearly it was me. So hopefully I can get a server side API going at some point soon and itll sort my issues. Thanks again for the response.